# Sale cannot be executed in Kadena Pact Marmalde

Tags: marmalade, pact-lang, kadena

Errors occur in the following conditions.

Running on local server (ubuntu on windows).

I deployed these [files](https://github.com/kadena-io/marmalade/tree/main/pact).

Token is minted.

The yaml file is generated via Django.
The generated file is then used to run the API request formatter to generate Json.

Template:

```
code:
  (marmalade.ledger.sale
    (read-msg 'token-id)
    (read-msg 'account)
    (read-decimal 'amount)
    (read-integer 'timeout)
  )
data:
  token-id: "${token_id}"
  account: "${account}"
  amount: ${amount}
  timeout: ${timeout}
  quote:
    price: "${price}"
    recipient-guard:
      keys:
        [ "${recipient_key}", ]
    recipient: ${recipient}

keyPairs:
  - public: ${marmalade_pub}
    secret: ${marmalade_sec}
    caps:
      - name: "marmalade.ledger.SALE"
        args: ["${token_id}", "${account}", ${amount}, ${timeout}]
```

Generated File：

```
code:
  (marmalade.ledger.sale
    (read-msg 'token-id)
    (read-msg 'account)
    (read-decimal 'amount)
    (read-integer 'timeout)
  )
data:
  token-id: "92496e13-4414-4c58-aceb-0c7d77120af2"
  account: "a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76"
  amount: 1.0
  timeout: 100
  quote:
    price: "1.0"
    recipient-guard:
      keys:
        [ "52d9d996e6cc77f48a1ff1b734224a2ce6cee3af84c3f6e1720047645e9c2c31", ]
    recipient: a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76

keyPairs:
  - public: b63680e667576818b713d5d398ad395610b522fbc53e08afe46a719a0a128fb5
    secret: 4242d66fac539660702ce4f9c01a39bb16f1d6b6c7110c6647010cb4dd041dd8
    caps:
      - name: "marmalade.ledger.SALE"
        args: ["92496e13-4414-4c58-aceb-0c7d77120af2", "a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76", 1.0, 100]
```

JSON:

```
b'{"cmds":[{"hash":"cD5gqQVmRj08xqOdqfKwLLL2eb76_j_eZDdzV4Xdkjg","sigs":[{"sig":"2fb4bbb496271a138c33a4c8b94cf4511c8ad494b5c0cca94a2d1f98a37025e865b1414116fe77e841fbe71c6430e
5da72209123a63e958b992f4e8ba1770103"}],"cmd":"{\\"networkId\\":null,\\"payload\\":{\\"exec\\":{\\"data\\":{\\"amount\\":1.0,\\"token-id\\":\\"92496e13-4414-4c58-aceb-0c7d7712
0af2\\",\\"account\\":\\"a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76\\",\\"quote\\":{\\"recipient-guard\\":{\\"keys\\":[\\"52d9d996e6cc77f48a1ff1b734224a2ce6cee3
af84c3f6e1720047645e9c2c31\\"]},\\"price\\":\\"1.0\\",\\"recipient\\":\\"a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76\\"},\\"timeout\\":100},\\"code\\":\\"(marmal
ade.ledger.sale (read-msg \'token-id) (read-msg \'account) (read-decimal 
\'amount) (read-integer \'timeout) 
)\\"}},\\"signers\\":[{\\"pubKey\\":\\"b63680e667576818b713d5d398a
d395610b522fbc53e08afe46a719a0a128fb5\\",\\"clist\\":[{\\"args\\":[\\"92496e13-4414-4c58-aceb-0c7d77120af2\\",\\"a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76\\",1
,100],\\"name\\":\\"marmalade.ledger.SALE\\"}]}],\\"meta\\":{\\"creationTime\\":0,\\"ttl\\":0,\\"gasLimit\\":0,\\"chainId\\":\\"\\",\\"gasPrice\\":0,\\"sender\\":\\"\\"},\\"n
once\\":\\"2022-07-20 09:53:05.975872 UTC\\"}"}]}\n'
```

The following error occurred when I posted the Json data to `request.post` on 'localhost:8080/api/v1/poll'.

{'cD5gqQVmRj08xqOdqfKwLLL2eb76_j_eZDdzV4Xdkjg': {'gas': 0, 'result': {'status': 'failure', 'error': {'callStack': [], 'type': 'EvalError', 'message': 'Managed capability not installed: (marmalade.ledger.OFFER "92496e13-4414-4c58-aceb-0c7d77120af2"  "a0fc037522ae0202052775f773e3cf823e3bd7640a12e80694b2dd76" 1.0 100)', 'info': ''}}, 'reqKey': 'cD5gqQVmRj08xqOdqfKwLLL2eb76_j_eZDdzV4Xdkjg', 'logs': None, 'metaData': None,
'continuation': None, 'txId': None}}

How do I get these to work properly?

P.S. I am Japanese and not an English speaker. I used a translation site to ask this question. Sorry if the description is missing.

Answer (score 0):

problem in your request is that you don't installed `marmalade.ledger.OFFER` capability correctly, timeout in `marmalade.ledger.OFFER` must be an object with datatype and value. for example `{ int: 999999 }`

**1.** first of all change your timeout input form `100` to `{ int: 100 }`.

**2.** you may have to add `coin.GAS` capability too, otherwise it will give gas error (if your code work without it then it's fine)

**3.** also you may missing `fungible` description in `data.quote` that will give error also. if it give error about `fungible` description then add blew code in `data.quote`, after `price`

```
fungible: {
    refName: {
        name: "coin",
        namespace: null,
    },
    refSpec: [
        {
            name: "fungible-v2",
            namespace: null,
        },
    ],
},
```